# KendoUI: Get The ID on Button Click in PHP

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

i have used kendoui grid like;

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:{
                transport: {
                    read: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/user_management/manage_users/list_view/"
                },
                schema:{
                    data: "data"
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "UserID",
                    hidden:true
                },
                {
                    field: "Username",
                    title:"Username"
                },
                { field: "FirstName",
                    title:"First Name"
                },
                {field:"MiddleNames"},
                {field:"LastName"},
                {field:"City"},
                {field:"Email"},
                {field:"Actions"},
                {command: { text: "View", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px"}
            ]
        });

    });


    function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //i want to get the id of the clicked row and pass that id to the next(redirected) page;
    }
</script>
```

How do I get the current clicked row id i.e `UserId` column value and pass that id(redirect) to the next page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the event that you receive, you get the row that it belongs to:

```
var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
```

And then you get the item using `dataItem`:

```
var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
```

So it would be:

```
function showDetails(e) {
    var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
    var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(row);
    alert("UserId is:" + item.UserId);
}
```

Comment: how do i get the UserId field value?

Comment: var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var da = e.data.valueOf("FirstName");
        alert(da);
But only getting object object, however i want the value

Comment: it's just a button with a name "View". I want, when a user click on it. I want to get the value of that clicked row i.e UserID field value. E.g 1 or 2, or 3...

Comment: still i am not getting it. Ok, just tell me how do i get the UserName field value. i mean, let's say i want to get the UserName field value. Let's if UserName = "John" in the grid

Comment: when i use item.UserId, i am getting null, and when i use just item, i am getting-> UserId is:[object Object]

Comment: Missing something... How do you invoke `showDetail`: when you click on view button, correct? in my last update of the answer you get all the fields of the row in `item`. `UserName` would be `item.UserName`.

Comment: Display it using `alert(JSON.stringify(item));`

Comment: love you man and your time. Thank you very much. I am doing this as overtime and i get it at last.